# python multiprocessing scheduling task

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have 8 CPU core and 200 tasks to done. Each tasks are isolate. There is no need to wait or share the result. I'm looking for a way to run 8 tasks/processes at a time (Maximum) and when one of them finished. The remaining task will automatic start process.

How to know when the child process was done and start a new child process. First I'm trying to use process(multiprocessing) and it's hard to figure out. Then I try to use pool and face with the pickle problem cause I need to use dynamic instantiate.

Edited : Adding my code of Pool

```
class Collectorparallel():

def fire(self,obj):
    collectorController = Collectorcontroller()
    collectorController.crawlTask(obj)

def start(self):
    log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)
    pluginObjectList = []
    for pluginName in self.settingModel.getAllCollectorName():
        name = pluginName.capitalize()
        #Get plugin class and instanitiate object
        module = __import__('plugins.'+pluginName,fromlist=[name])
        pluginClass = getattr(module,name)
        pluginObject = pluginClass()
        pluginObjectList.append(pluginObject)



    pool = Pool(8)
    jobs = pool.map(self.fire,pluginObjectList)
    pool.close()

    print pluginObjectList
```

pluginObjectList got something like

```
[<plugins.name1.Name1 instance at 0x1f54290>, <plugins.name2.Name2 instance at 0x1f54f38>]
```

PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup **builtin**.instancemethod failed

but the Process version work fine

Comment: The solution is to use `multiprocessing.Pool`. How to solve the window's problem of pickling *completely* depends on the code. **Post some code!** If you can write a *small* and *self-contained* example that we can use for testing and that shows clearly your use case.

Comment: @Bakuriu I had added my code

Answer (score 1):

Warning this is kinda subjective to deployment and situation but my current setup is as follows

I have a worker program, I fire up 6 copies (I have 6 cores).
Each worker does the following;

1. Connect to a Redis instance
2. Try and pop some work of a specific list
3. Pushes back logging information
4. Either idles or terminates on a lack of work in the 'queue'

Then each program is essentially standalone while still doing the work you require with a separate queuing system. As you have no go-between on your processes, this might be a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in multiprocessing in Python but I tried some fiew things with this help http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm and this one too http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Basic-Threading-in-Python/1/ .

You can for example use this method `isAlive` which answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is trivial. First of all, note that *methods* cannot be pickled. In fact only the types listed in [`pickle`'s documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) can be pickled:

> - `None`, `True`, and `False`
> - integers, long integers, floating point numbers, complex numbers
> - normal and Unicode strings
> - `tuple`s, `list`s, `set`s, and `dict`ionaries containing only picklable objects
> - *functions **defined at the top level of a module***
> - *built-in functions **defined at the top level of a module***
> - *classes that are **defined at the top level of a module***
> - instances of such classes whose `__dict__` or the result of calling `__getstate__()` is picklable (see section The pickle protocol
>     for details).
>
> [...]
>
> Note that *functions* (built-in and user-defined) *are pickled by
>   “fully qualified” name reference, **not by value***. This means that
>   **only the function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the function is defined in**. Neither the function’s code, nor any of
>   its function attributes are pickled. Thus *the defining module must be
>   importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain
>   the named object*, otherwise an exception will be raised. [4]
>
> Similarly, **classes are pickled by named reference**, so the same
>   restrictions in the unpickling environment apply. Note that *none of
>   the class’s code or data is pickled*[...]

Clearly a method isn't a function defined at the top level of a module, hence it cannot be pickled.(read carefully that part of the documentation to avoid future problems with pickle!) But it is absolutely trivial to replace the method with a global function and passing `self` as additional parameter:

```
import itertools as it


def global_fire(argument):
    self, obj = argument
    self.fire(obj)


class Collectorparallel():

    def fire(self,obj):
        collectorController = Collectorcontroller()
        collectorController.crawlTask(obj)

    def start(self):
        log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)
        pluginObjectList = []
        for pluginName in self.settingModel.getAllCollectorName():
            name = pluginName.capitalize()
            #Get plugin class and instanitiate object
            module = __import__('plugins.'+pluginName,fromlist=[name])
            pluginClass = getattr(module,name)
            pluginObject = pluginClass()
            pluginObjectList.append(pluginObject)



        pool = Pool(8)
        jobs = pool.map(global_fire, zip(it.repeat(self), pluginObjectList))
        pool.close()

        print pluginObjectList
```

Note that, since `Pool.map` calls the given function with only one argument, we have to "pack together" both `self` and the actual argument. To do this I have `zip`ped `it.repeat(self)` and the original iterable.

If you do not care about the order in which the calls are done then using `pool.imap_unordered` *might* provide better performances. However it returns an iterable and not a list, so if you want the list of results you'll have to do `jobs = list(pool.imap_unordered(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this code will remove all pickling problems.

```
class Collectorparallel():

def __call__(self,cNames):
    for pluginName in cNames:
        name = pluginName.capitalize()
        #Get plugin class and instanitiate object
        module = __import__('plugins.'+pluginName,fromlist=[name])
        pluginClass = getattr(module,name)
        pluginObject = pluginClass()
        pluginObjectList.append(pluginObject)

    collectorController = Collectorcontroller()
    collectorController.crawlTask(obj)

def start(self):
    log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)
    pool = Pool(8)
    jobs = pool.map(self,self.settingModel.getAllCollectorName())
    pool.close()
```

What has happened here is that `Collectorparallel` has been turned into a callable. The list of plugin names is used as the iterable for the pool, the actual determination of the plugins and their instantiation is done in each of the worker processes, and the class instance object is used as the callable for each worker process.